Sandbox problems with Arduino IDEs with 24.04
I have just updated to 24.04 and am having my first teething problems. I cannot run my Arduino IDE since updating, if I try it in the terminal I get the warning

"FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(158)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was
found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without
sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that
/home/stevetux/ArduinoLatest/arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit/chrome-sandbox
is owned by root and has mode 4755."

I considered just changing the permissions of arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit/chrome-sandbox but if I try and open my arduino-lab-micropython-ide a different sandbox (MicroPythonIDE/chrome-sandbox) needs the permission altered.
Both of these IDEs were working perfectly under 23.10 and I don't know how many other applications are affected as I have only just upgraded, so is there a fix to this issue which doesn't involve changing the permissions on lots of files?
Edit: I have discovered that I can run the IDEs if I put --no-sandbox at the end of the launch command. But I have no idea if this has security or other implications. Advice would be appreciated.

Please can you try if the apparmore rule is working? https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/2429

The security implications of --no-sandbox is that your Arduino IDE will not be run in a sandbox. Rather, it will run in your regular environment.
You should make /home/stevetux/ArduinoLatest/arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit/chrome-sandbox a setuid root binary (owned by root, uses UID:GID from file ownership, rather than using $USER's UID:GID). It requires the power of root to setup the sandbox. Then your Arduino IDE should run in its own sandbox. The same should apply to your other IDE.

The issue comes from Ubuntu 24.04 deprecating unprivileged kernel namespaces, which the Arduino IDE (and other applications) rely on for their sandboxes
To solve this, you can create a new AppArmor profile for the Arduino IDE. Assuming you installed it in /home/username/bin/arduino (that's the whole filename), you can do something like sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/home.username.bin.arduino (or nano, or some other editor) and write:
abi <abi/4.0>,
include <tunables/global>
profile arduino /home/username/bin/arduino flags=(unconfined) {
  userns,
  include if exists <local/arduino>
}

Then run sudo service apparmor reload
As an alternative, that still lets you run things without --no-sandbox, you can disable this new Ubuntu policy by running sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=1
Source

If I have to create a new AppArmor profile for each IDE I might as well simply change the owner and prmissions for each IDE instead. Is either method preferable?

@SteveInBavaria the AppArmor method is preferrable because it doesn't expose your computer to security vulnerabilities. If you don't want it, try sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=1 or adding kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0 to /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf first. It is better than giving root permissions to external apps and you only have to do it once. The source I linked explains it all.
